# Windows Service And Dll On A Network Drive

Tags: dll, com, windows-services, network-drive

I have a Windows Service that has to use a dll file on a network drive. When I was connected to  this network drive, I added this dll as a reference to my Windows Service. Automatically 2 more reference files were created by adding this dll file. There's a code on this service that simply creates an instance of a class from dll. While I am debugging this code on Visual Studio 2010, when I press F10 (Step Over), it throws an exception:

"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {65EB3876-89FF-459F-BF24-02E8DD7F2DB2} failed due to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)."

I use same dll and same codes on a Windows Forms Application for testing. It gives no error and creates a class instance successfully.

Could it be something related to permission for network drive?

Comment: Is that CLSID registered?  Search the registry for it.  Either the network dll is a COM object that needs to be registered or it's referencing a COM object that needs to be registered.

Comment: @Samuel Neff I searched regedit for "65EB3876-89FF-459F-BF24-02E8DD7F2DB2". Yes, it is registered. Do I need to register other two references that were automatically added when I added the dll on network drive as a reference?

Comment: Is it registered using UNC path or via mapped drive letter?

Comment: @RomanR. it is registered via mapped drive letter.

Answer (score 1):

Windows service is likely to run under different credentials, so your drive mappings are not "visible" for this account and hence the path to the DLL does not exist. The error code indicates you exactly this problem.

[Services and Redirected Drives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685143%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Drive mappings exist across logon contexts, so if an application is
>   running in the context of the LocalService account, then any other
>   service running in that context may have access to the mapped drive.

You need to re-register the DLL using UNC path, or copy DLL into local drive and re-register there, or set service to run with the same credentials as interactive usre the drive mappings exist for.

Comment: I have tried to re-register DLL using UNC path but it doesn't work. Still "The specified module could not be found." exception.

Comment: Good catch, I agreed that the service running as a user that does not have network access is the most likely issue.